# use of undeclared type UISegment swift tvOS

Tags: swift2, uisegmentedcontrol, tvos, semantic-ui-segment

I am working on tvOS application & using `UISegmentedControl` . On `didUpdateFocusInContext` i had following code to change the image of UISegment like -

```
 override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator)
 {   
    if let previousItem = context.previouslyFocusedView as! UISegment    
            {
            if previousItem.selectedSegmentIndex == 0    
                {    
              previousItem.insertSegmentWithImage(UIImage(named: "white_save_star.png"), atIndex: previousItem.selectedSegmentIndex, animated: false)    
                }    
                else if previousItem.selectedSegmentIndex == 1    
                {    
              previousItem.insertSegmentWithImage(UIImage(named: "white_goto-arrow.png"), atIndex: previousItem.selectedSegmentIndex, animated: false)    
                }         

            }    
    if let nextItem = context.nextFocusedView as? UISegment    
            {    
                if nextItem.selectedSegmentIndex == 0    
                {    
                    nextItem.insertSegmentWithImage(UIImage(named: "Blue_save_star.png"), atIndex: nextItem.selectedSegmentIndex, animated: false)    
                }    
                else if nextItem.selectedSegmentIndex == 1    
                {    
                    nextItem.insertSegmentWithImage(UIImage(named: "Blue_goto-arrow.png"), atIndex: nextItem.selectedSegmentIndex, animated: false)

         }   
         }    
        }
```

but getting following error   `use of undeclared type UISegment`

while printing `po context.previouslyFocusedView`

```
result -
▿ Optional<UIView>

  - Some : <UISegment: 0x7f861c87da10; frame = (0 0; 300 70); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f861c87e180>>
```

as you can see in output it is clear that `UISegment` class exists.

any help will be appreciated

Comment: And you have `import UIKit`?

Comment: Yes, I had import UIKit

Comment: Have you found any public interface for `UISegment`?  As far as I can tell, they're always referenced as index values within the control. `selectedSegmentIndex` is a method of `UISegmentedControl`.

Comment: No i can't get any public interface for UISegment. I can get UISegmentedControl

Comment: Right, so the answer becomes, "Use the control instead".

Comment: but from the control , i can't get UISegment & i need UISegment  to typecast the value of context.nextFocusedView or context.previouslyFocusedView

Answer (score 0):

Here is something which works

```
 if String(describing: type(of: context.nextFocusedView!)) == "UISegment"{
        //handle segment focus
 }
```